# Does a spaceship heat up if frictional force acts on it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, friction, thermal-radiation, drag

I was doing a homework question:

### [image: Homework question]

*The answer that I have pasted in the box is the given answer.*

I understand that the total energy of the spaceship decreases as it experiences friction, and as a result of that the total energy (KE + PE) of the spaceship is converted into thermal energy, thus thermal energy of the spaceship is lost to the surroundings.

My confusion is this: If thermal energy of the spaceship is lost to the surroundings, the temperature of the spaceship should decrease. On the other hand, doesn't friction cause the spaceship to heat up and thus the temperature increases?

So does the spaceship heat up or cool down?

Comment: This article may answer your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_thermal_protection_system

Comment: My question is about the energy exchange rather than the design of space shuttles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...... as a result of that the total energy (KE + PE) of the spaceship is converted into thermal energy, thus thermal energy of the spaceship is lost to the surroundings.

Due to the action of the frictional force between the spacecraft and the air some of the mechanical energy (kinetic and gravitational potential energy) of the spacecraft is converted into thermal energy.
The air around the spacecraft **and** the spacecraft itself gain this thermal energy and as a result the temperature of the surrounding air **and** the temperature of the spacecraft both increase.
The hot spacecraft loses some of the thermal energy that it has gained to the surroundings but not all of it as the spacecraft travels through the atmosphere.